# Not-for-profit universities that offer computer science undergraduate degree online?

Tags: education

There are many masters degree programs in computer science online offered by reputable organizations. However, I've found very few bachelors only degree programs offered by non for-profit institutions.

I am looking for a degree in computer science and also any programs for entrepreneurship/management or algorithmic trading.

I've found only 2 programs so far that fit:

http://www.regis.edu/regis.asp?sctn=cpcis&p1=ap&p2=cs&p3=ol

http://depaul.edu

Requirements:

100% online undergraduate non-profit

Options: Bachelor of Science Bachelor of Arts

Bonuses: accelerated recognized ABET cost effective

Update:
I've answered my question with a list. If anyone knows an online program that combines skills in entrepreneurship (getting capital, starting a business) or algorithmic trading with a computer program that would be ideal.. maybe too much to ask though

Comment: You probably want to have "accredited" in there, at least for US universities, presumably under "Requirements:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found these non-for profit, accredited, online-only programs/colleges:

Uni Illinois, very tough/limited CS program, may have an information systems
http://www.uis.edu

private
http://www.regis.edu/

private, accelerated, flexible, quarter system, minor
http://depaul.edu

public, expensive, computer science and information system
http://umuc.edu

UMASS Online
http://www.umassonline.net/

Penn State World
http://www.worldcampus.psu.edu/

Troy website not working, a minus but cost is good.
http://www.troy.edu/ecampus/programs/ugdegreeprograms.htm

Eastern Carolina -- a business program, probably cheapest option
http://www.ecu.edu/business/undergraduateprograms.cfm

Since 1889
http://www.saintleo.edu/Academics/School-of-Business/Undergraduate-Degree-Programs/Computer-Information-Systems/Degree-Requirements

newer public school
http://www.rsu.edu/rsuonline/

Columbia College
http://www.ccis.edu/

Drexel Online (expensive)
http://www.drexel.com/

List of others that might fit
http://oedb.org/rankings

May be others in this list
http://www.forbes.com/bow/b2c/category.jhtml?id=147

*very tough to find these*

Answer (score 3):

I ran across [TUI International Online University](http://www.tuiu.edu/) which I thought looked promising. It's based in California and accredited.

[The University of California will test a fully-online program](http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/article.cgi?f=/c/a/2010/07/14/BAC61EEDI4.DTL), but as the article says, "it's unclear when students could enroll."

Other possibly useful resources for you:

- [Online Degree Reviews](http://www.onlinedegreereviews.org/)
  Along with seeing what students think of their schools, you can also search for schools and programs
- [California Virtual Campus Catalog](http://www.cvc.edu/students/programs/?q=&degree=1&subject=9)
  Lets you search for online programs by degree and subject.

Comment: @Don Nope, look below. I've updated my list. Took me a ton of researching to find these.

Comment: @Don TUI is out because it is for-profit. They may be good schools but not worth the risk or possible trouble.

Comment: @Curtis - I don't understand why a reasonably-priced for-profit would have risk or trouble issues, but that's your call. I've added a couple of resources that you didn't seem to have yet. And btw, it's "Dori" not "Don".

Answer (score 1):

The [University of South Africa](http://www.unisa.ac.za/) offer both undergraduate and postgraduate degrees in mathematics, computer science, information technology, and all the rest.

There's also the [Open University](http://www.open.ac.uk/).

Answer (score 1):

I got mine from University of Maryland University College. http://umuc.edu/

UMUC is part of the Maryland state university system and is a public institution. Their computer science program is pretty good and entirely online.

UMUC is also regionally accredited by the US Dept. of Education. http://umuc.edu/gen/accred.shtml

Comment: Thanks. That's what I meant with UMD. This is the only state program, non for-profit, that I've found. Other then the UIS with is ABET but very tough to get into.

Answer (score 0):

**Troy University**

I am in the midst of my first term at Troy.  I had a list similar to yours, and Troy fit the bill.  In the end, it came down to Troy's program or UMUC.  Troy was half the cost for what appeared to be the same level of education, so I chose it.  It is regionally accredited; however, it is NOT recognized by ABET.  That is to say Troy University as a whole, not just their online program, is not recognized by ABET.  Troy makes no distinction between their online or on-campus programs.  The coursework is the same for both.  It operates on a term system.  They have five terms a year.  Your first term you may only take two classes, but after that, you can appeal to take more classes per term.  So far, the institution's staff has been very knowledgeable, helpful, and prompt to respond to my questions.  I enjoy the experience but YMMV.  I'm not sure what you're situation is, but I'm 30 with a family and have already completed a B.A. and a M.A. the traditional way.  I want to make a career change, and this was the best possible scenario for me to make it happen.  Also, I don't know how much schoolin' you're looking to get, but while there are only a handful of accredited B.S. Comp sci programs available online, there are several M.S. Comp sci programs online from most of the major schools.  That is the route that I am probably going to take.  Hope this helps.